# How to send\recv non char data with winsock (c++)?

Tags: c++, windows, networking, winsock

I'm exchanging data via winsock using **sendto** and **recvfrom** functions, but the second param in each is **char* buf**. I would like to send a custom data like **MyStruct***, but I can't find analogs of those functions to work with **void***. I just afraid, sending data in string format and then parsing it might be slow and ineffective. But still, maybe there is a strong reason to force programmers to send data in that way ? Any information about situation and any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `struct` does *not* contain any pointers or handles and the receiver is written by you using the same compiler and compile flags, and you do not care about portability (e.g. big-endian architectures), then you can just cast your `MyStruct*` to `char*` and it will work.

In ever other case, you'll die a horrible death. No, seriously. It won't work. Pointers and handles are not meaningful on another machine, and using a different compiler or compilation flags may result in the `struct` having a slightly different layout or padding, rendering it useless.

Sending structures via the network usually, with very few exceptions, requires [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Damon. I do planning portability, so thank you for letting me know about serializationю Gonna dig for it and try to figure out if serialization\deserialization will slow app down.

Comment: Whether it slows down the application doesn't really matter much -- it must work. If it doesn't work, it's no use even if it's fast. When serialization is necessary, it's necessary. Before re-inventing the wheel, look if [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) or [msgpack](http://msgpack.org/) are acceptable for you. They're reasonably fast and efficient, and using something that already works saves weeks/months of your time.

Answer (score 4):

it doesn't matter whether it's `char*` or `void*` socket works with raw bytes anyway. So just cast your buffer to `(char*)` and that's it